# Why after setting up a router as an access point I can't reach it anymore?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a Xiaomi mi router, and I have made this simple configuration:

```
internet --- main router (with internet)------lan cable----xiaomi router
```

I want to use the wifi from the xiaomi in another room. So I have disable DHCP on the xiaomi, setted up the wireless, and restarted it. To make this changes I connected to the router default address: `192.168.31.1`. After having restarted everything, I am able to access to internet from the deviced connected to the Xiaomi mi router wifi, but can't access the router anymore to the address `192.168.31.1`. If I go on my macbook network panel to see which router I am connected to, it indicates my main router with the IP (192.168.178.1).

But I am connected to the xiaomi router. It is like my xiaomi in "invisible", but I am not an expert of network, so I can't understand why, and how I can do a proper configuration to achieve the same result but mantaining the access to my xiaomi router.

Comment: Why did you disable DHCP?

Comment: I have read it on a guide

Comment: Reading it in a guide doesn't tell me much. Nor does it tell me why the guide is disabling DHCP. Does your "main router" have DHCP enabled? Or is it just a broadband modem provided by your internet company?

Comment: sorry I know I can't help much! anyway On the main router I have DHCP enabled!

Comment: When you turned off DHCP, you disabled the ability of the router to set IP addresses. They now come from the main router. This explains why you can no longer use `192.168.31.1` to access the router. Have you tried to access the router at `192.168.178.1`?

Comment: @CharlieRB yes it goes directly to the main router

Comment: You have basically turned your router into a hub. You will need to factory reset it. When you set it up again, don't turn off the DHCP. The router will give out IP addresses to all devices connected to it. It will get the Internet signal from the main router and make it accessible to all connected devices.

Comment: @CharlieRB Isn't it the right (or at least, better) way to let the main router do the routing and DHCP job though?

Comment: That depends on the main router configuration and purpose. If it's a router given by the ISP, there may be restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

It’s years old, but it deserves an answer!

First of all: There is absolutely no need to reset anything.

Your Xiaomi router is still reachable at `192.168.31.1`. However, to communicate with it, you need to be in the same subnet. Currently, with DHCP from your main router, you’re in the `192.168.178.0/24` network while you want to be in the `192.168.31.0/24` network.

To access your Xiaomi router, *manually* change your PCs IP address to `192.168.31.2`. You will not be able to access the Internet like this, though.

To be able to access your Xiaomi router during normal operation, you need to change its IP address. You could use `192.168.178.2`, for example. Just make sure there is no IP address conflict. Preferably, the address would also be outside the DHCP range of your main router.

Comment: Hi! Have the same lan config as the OP with xiaomi router 3 (main router has 192.168.100.0 subnet) and following your advice tried to configure my laptop IP manually to 192.168.31.2, set  subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 and default gateway to 192.168.31.1. However it didn't work - pings to 192.168.31.1 time out and its not accessible via http (also timeout). Any ideas where to look for the reason ? Thanks.

Comment: You may have the same Xiaomi router, but it’s apparently set to use a different IP address. I’m sure there’s a question (and answer) about finding this IP address somewhere here on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i managed to solve it.

After following the setup to set it as an repeater/access point the main router gave it a new ip. I found the new ip by logging into the main router and checking connected devices.

I could log in using that ip if i was connected directly to the main routers network but not while i was connected to the xiaomi wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need, take a look. You need to make sure the plug is not the "Internet" port instead its the 2 other port. https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-configure-mi-wi-fi-as-second-router-to-extend-existing-network-same-ssid-roaming

Comment: er. The AP works. He dosen't know how to contact it.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda amusingly, the 'easiest' way to sort this out is by network scanning your network and identifying which one of these is your AP.

[Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/) is a pretty nice front end for nmap.

[image]

These are the settings I use. You'll want to change the target to "192.168.31.1-255", and hit scan. Then go have a cup of coffee. This takes a little while. It seems to do nothing at this time so be patient.

Essentially this gives you a list of hosts, and what they are running. Some interpretation is required depending on your device.

Once its done, it looks like this

[image]

You can click through each host, and interpret the output

The output looks something like this ideally - it tells you what ports are open, which is useless here, and then this information. The service info line is typically what you want in this case.

```
MAC Address: AC:22:00:00:00:00 (Asustek Computer)

Device type: general purpose

Running: Linux 2.6.X

OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6

OS details: Linux 2.6.8 - 2.6.27

Network Distance: 1 hop

Service Info: Host: RT-N56U; Device: WAP
```

This tells me My MAC address (and I can google the first 4 letters there to doublecheck who made it), what I run, and *what it actually is* - a RT-N56U access point.

In the case of my other AP, there's a bunch of junk data.

```
MAC Address: C4:A8:1D:84:F3:59 (Unknown)

No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see http://nmap.org/submit/ ).....

Network Distance: 1 hop

Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/h:dlink:dir-865l:1.07, cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
```

Zenmap can't *quite* identify what it is, but gives you enough information to ID what it is - look at the service info line. It tells me it runs linux, its a CPE (consumer premises equipment) and its a dlink, dir-865l running firmware 1.07